# AWK - understanding different outputs obtained using FILENAME and OFS

Tags: awk

Input File 1: clnd.csv

```
20180805,08/05/2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,27,WEEK 27,01,SUNDAY
20180812,08/12/2018,w28_2018,WK28 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,28,WEEK 28,01,SUNDAY
20180819,08/19/2018,w29_2018,WK29 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,29,WEEK 29,01,SUNDAY
20180826,08/26/2018,w30_2018,WK30 2018,m07_2018,AUG 2018,q03_2018,Q03 2018,h02_2018,H02 2018,a2018,FY2018,30,WEEK 30,01,SUNDAY
```

Input File 2: data.csv

```
w27_2018,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
w28_2018,257,1,7.97,0.00,24.26
w29_2018,257,1,34.86,0.00,24.26
w30_2018,257,1,3.29,0.00,24.26
```

GNU-Awk commands used:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {y=substr($12,3,4); a[ARGV[2],$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; next} {$1=a[ARGV[2],$1]; } 1' OFS=, clnd.csv data.csv  >> my_report_1.csv
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {y=substr($12,3,4); a[ARGV[2],$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; next} {$1=a[FILENAME,$1]; } 1' OFS=, clnd.csv data.csv  >> my_report_2.csv
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR {y=substr($12,3,4); a[ARGV[2],$3]=y FS $3 FS $4; next} {$1=a[FILENAME,$1]; } 1' clnd.csv data.csv  >> my_report_3.csv
```

Output obtained: cat my_report_?.csv

==> my_report_1.csv <==

```
2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
2018,w28_2018,WK28 2018,257,1,7.97,0.00,24.26
2018,w29_2018,WK29 2018,257,1,34.86,0.00,24.26
2018,w30_2018,WK30 2018,257,1,3.29,0.00,24.26
```

==> my_report_2.csv <==

```
,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
,257,1,7.97,0.00,24.26
,257,1,34.86,0.00,24.26
,257,1,3.29,0.00,24.26
```

==> my_report_3.csv <==

```
2018,w27_2018,WK27 2018,257,1,26.20,0.00,24.26
2018,w28_2018,WK28 2018,257,1,7.97,0.00,24.26
2018,w29_2018,WK29 2018,257,1,34.86,0.00,24.26
2018,w30_2018,WK30 2018,257,1,3.29,0.00,24.26
```

Can you please explain why these outputs are different? My understanding was FILENAME will hold the name of the file being read and setting OFS in the beginning and end, like I have done, shouldn't make any difference as either way it should be set before any record is being read. Thanks in advance!

P.S: I am using GNU Awk 3.1.7 on Oracle Linux Server release 6.10. Expected output is as it appears in my_report_1.csv and my_report_3.csv

Comment: In the second version argv[2] does not match FILENAME at the critical moment, because `OFS=,` is being inserted as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you explain it further? In 2nd example, similar to 3rd, OFS should be set before even any input is read, right? And, how does OFS affect FILENAME, as I think it will always be set to ARGV[ARGIND]?

Comment: OFS doesn't affect FILENAME, but it can affect `argv` as you can see in the more detailed explanation in my answer below. If it's still not clear let me know I'll try to explain further.

Comment: Your example makes it very clear. Appreciate it!

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Appreciate the question --- I had never thought about how the different ways of setting OFS affect the argument list. Always learning on SO.

Comment: Only (c) set variables in the argument list if you **need** to do so to give them different values before processing different files. In all other cases (a) use `-v` to set variables if you want escape sequences interpreted and either (d) populate variables from ENVIRON[] or (f) from **values** in the argument list otherwise. See c, a, d, and f examples at http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 (which I wrote about 15-20 years ago IIRC and now am not proud of but it still has some uses!)

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks again. It might be 15-20 years old but is still very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you are changing the numbering of the arguments by specifying `OFS` as a trailing argument to awk instead of using the `-v` option.

In particular this is a problem for your second example because you are depending on the fact that `argv[2]` has the same value as `FILENAME` while processing the second file.

You can see the difference here:

```
$ gawk -v OFS=, -f a.awk a b
    ARGV[0] = gawk
    ARGV[1] = a
    ARGV[2] = b

$ gawk -f a.awk OFS=, a b
    ARGV[0] = gawk
    ARGV[1] = OFS=,
    ARGV[2] = a
    ARGV[3] = b
```

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you!!